# JavaScript running before Tridion GUI Resources are loaded

Tags: cme, web8.5, upgrade, javascript

Another question from our Tridion GUI 8.5 upgrade.

I have discovered that many of the problems we've been facing in this upgrade are because the Tridion Resources (<cc:tridionManager>) are not loading until AFTER the on-page javascript runs.

Can I move the javascript to an external file, and load it somehow through Tridion manager?  Or is there a "fully loaded" Tridion event I can listen for before triggering our javascript?

Currently I'm using a setTimeout, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

```
<cc:tridionmanager runat="server" Editor="CME" IsStandAloneView="false">
    <dependencies runat="server">       
        <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</dependency>
        <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Views</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</cc:tridionmanager>
<script type="text/javascript> INLINE JAVASCRIPT HERE IS RUNNING BEFORE RESOURCES LOAD</script>
```

Comment: AFAIK there hasn't been any changes in this area; in your example, I would indeed expect inline code to execute before the dependencies have been fully loaded (also before 8.5). Could you clarify what the context is here? Is this your own dialog? Or are you extending an existing view?